# Using JSON Stringify with a variable to push to Node server

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, node.js

I am trying to push the `base64` of an image in `<canvas>` to a Node.js server. I have tried many approaches, but most other answers on Stackoverflow centre around this idea, however it doesn't work for me:

```
saveImage: function(e) {
        var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvasElement');
        var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();

        var image = 'image';
        var object = {};
        object[image] = base64;

        console.log(object);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/save',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(object)
        });
    },
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Also, since you log `object` already, mind telling us what the result of that is?

Comment: Sure, if I use: 'data: {hi: "there"}', it will console log on the server. If I try to add the variable, nothing logs on the server.

Comment: ...and the console.log: Object {image: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABQAA…sokX2YZ/nyOBLz35OTaL/D/ulMLu3RLMCAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"}

Comment: @JohnRobertPett — So it works if you don't send JSON and doesn't if you do send JSON? Sounds like the server isn't set up to expect a JSON formatted request.

Comment: Sorry, it is, I omitted a bit. If I put this as the data attribute in the AJAX post, then it will log on the server. So I can get this working currently: JSON.stringify({hi: "there"})

Comment: What if you remove the `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: It doesn't do anything.

Comment: Check what's the server's response with the Chrome Dev Tools, in the Network tab, and post it here please

Comment: Just says 'pending'. This is what I have on the server listening for the 'POST': app.use('/save', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});